# How to concatenate the graph data on single chart using Am4charts?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, amcharts

> This below is image is what i was trying to develop. Separate the graphs by the type key present in the response and also if the multiple pay cycles having the data for the same dates still show them separately. Each pay cycle should be separated by a vertical line.
> So here the problem which im facing is im not able to concatenate the pay cycles one after another in a single graph.
> [image: I want to create a graph series in which the pay cycle data should be concatenated one after another as show in the figure. Also, if the multiple pay cycle having the data on the same date the it should not look like a clustered chart for the same dates. I mean the data should be separated under each pay cycle.]Below code i have written using react.js and am4charts but not able to figure out the solution for it.ColumnSeries is created for each payCycle based on the filters.

```
const GraphComponentContainer = ({ history, filters }) => {                                  const [message] = useState(null);                                                             useEffect(() => {recentTrendGraph(ExpandedRowGraphData, filters);}, [filters]);                 const recentTrendGraph = (graphData, filter) => {                            console.log(filter);                                                                      const chart = am4core.create(recent_trend, am4charts.XYChart);                                            const testData = Object.keys(graphData)
  .filter(paycycle => filter.includes(paycycle))
  .flatMap(payCycle => graphData[payCycle]);

chart.data = testData;
// chart.data = filter.map(paycycles => ExpandedRowGraphData[paycycles]);

const categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "date";
categoryAxis.title.text = "Pay Dates";
categoryAxis.title.fill = am4core.color("#707070");
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeWidth = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.cellStartLocation = 0.3;
categoryAxis.renderer.cellEndLocation = 0.7;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;

const label = categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template;
label.wrap = true;
label.fontSize = 12;
label.fontWeight = 300;
label.color = "#707070";
label.marginTop = -60;
label.rotation = -45;

label.adapter.add("date", text => {
  return moment(text, "YYYY-MM-DD").format("MMM DD YYYY");
});

// eslint-disable-next-line func-names
categoryAxis.events.on("sizechanged", function(ev) {
  const axis = ev.target;
  const cellWidth = axis.pixelWidth / (axis.endIndex - axis.startIndex);
  axis.renderer.labels.template.maxWidth = cellWidth;
  axis.renderer.labels.template.maxHeight = 100;
});

const valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.title.text = "Accuracy in %";
valueAxis.title.fill = am4core.color("#707070");
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeWidth = 0;
valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 1;
valueAxis.renderer.line.stroke = am4core.color("#eee");
valueAxis.min = -5;
valueAxis.max = 110;

valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("text", (text, target) => {
  if (
    (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.value < 0) ||
    (target.dataItem && target.dataItem.value > 100)
  ) {
    return "";
  }
  return text;
});

const numberFormatter = new am4core.NumberFormatter();
numberFormatter.numberFormat = "#.a%";
valueAxis.numberFormatter = numberFormatter;

const yAxisLabel = valueAxis.renderer.labels.template;
yAxisLabel.fontSize = 12;
yAxisLabel.fontWeight = 300;
yAxisLabel.color = "#707070";
yAxisLabel.marginTop = -20;

valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.strokeOpacity = 0.5;
valueAxis.renderer.grid.template.stroke = am4core.color("#4f5460");

const seriesMap = {};


filter.forEach(payCycle => {
  const series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series.name = `${payCycle} Pay Dates`;
  series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
  series.dataFields.categoryX = "date";
  series.columns.template.fill = am4core.color("#144182");
  series.strokeWidth = 3;
  series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(60);
  series.columns.template.tooltipText = `[bold]{name}[/]\n[font-size:14px]{categoryX}: {valueY}`;
  series.columns.template.maxHeight = 40;
  series.columns.template.maxWidth = 40;

  series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
  series.tooltip.getFillFromObject = false;
  series.tooltip.background.fill = am4core.color("#fff");
  series.tooltip.label.fill = am4core.color("#00");
  series.columns.template.tooltipHTML = `
  <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr; gap: 8px; background-color: #FFFFFF; padding: 8px;">
    <div style="grid-column: span 2; background-color: #F8F8F8;">
      <span style="font-size: 14px; background-color: #F8F8F8; padding: 2px; font-weight: bold;">Oct 15, 2023</span><br/>
    </div>
    <div style="grid-column: span 2; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
      <span style="font-size: 12px;">Total employees paid </span>
      <span style="font-weight: bold;">70</span>
    </div>
    <div style="grid-column: span 2; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
      <span style="font-size: 12px;">No. of correct payments made per employee</span>
      <span style="font-weight: bold;">80</span>
    </div>
    <div style="grid-column: span 2; background-color: #FFFFFF;">
      <span style="font-size: 12px;">Payroll Accuracy Rate </span>
      <span style="font-weight: bold;">90</span>
    </div>
  </div>
`;

  // Filter data based on payCycle and type
  const filteredData = graphData[payCycle].filter(
    item => item.type === payCycle
  );

  // Set data for each series
  series.data = filteredData;

  const columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
  columnTemplate.column.cornerRadius(5, 5, 5, 5);
  columnTemplate.strokeOpacity = 0;

  seriesMap[payCycle] = series;
});
```

> ```
>   const ExpandedRowGraphData = {     weekly: [       {         date: "2023-11-08",         type: "weekly",         key: "1",         value: 90,         color: "#144182"       },       {         date: "2023-11-15",         type: "weekly",         key: "2",         value: 96,         color: "#144182"       },       {         date: "2023-11-22",         type: "weekly",         key: "3",         value: 95,         color: "#144182"       },       {         date: "2023-11-29",         type: "weekly",         key: "4",         value: 95,         color: "#144182"       }     ],     biWeekly: [       {         date: "2023-11-15",         type: "biWeekly",         key: "1",         value: 93,         color: "#144182"       },       {         date: "2023-11-29",         type: "biWeekly",         key: "2",         value: 91,         color: "#144182"       },       {         date: "2023-11-01",         type: "biWeekly",         key: "3",         value: 90,         color: "#144182"       }     ],     semiMonthly: [       {         date: "2023-11-15",         type: "semiMonthly",         key: "1",         value: 86,         color: "#144182"       },       {         date: "2023-11-29",         type: "semiMonthly",         key: "2",         value: 88,         color: "#144182"       }     ],     monthly: [       {         date: "2023-11-30",         type: "monthly",         key: "1",         value: 81,         color: "#144182"       }     ]   };
> ```
>
> [image: I tried to concatenate all the pay cycles but its showing as a clustered chart]

Comment: Is there any one who can help me to resolve this issue?